# forcing device to use specific connection

Tags: javascript, cordova, connection, wifi

for security reasons my App has to use a specific wifi connection to send data.

is there a pluigin or way todo that?

Connection state and detection is all working fine, but how to force it to use a specific connection?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in javascript alone. You might be able to hack something by changing the DNS server on the router to redirect a perticular request somewhere and use that to validate you're on the right connection.

Comment: hi, i know i would have to use some kind of plugin, but can it be done?

Comment: I doubt such a plugin exists. Modifying the settings on the router might be your best bet. Perhaps you can add a HTTP header there, that you can read with javascript afterwards.

Comment: Hi, found a solution, will have to write a plugin for phonegap, but it can be done.